# FOREIGN KEY constraint that should allow NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created my tables like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [pdMaterialMaster] (
  [MaterialID] varchar(18),
  [BottleNeckCode] varchar(2),
  PRIMARY KEY ([MaterialID])
);

CREATE TABLE [pdBottleNeckCodes] (
  [BottleNeckCode] varchar(2),
  [BottleNeckDescription] varchar(40),
  PRIMARY KEY ([BottleNeckCode])
);
```

Then, added constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE pdMaterialMaster     
 ADD FOREIGN KEY (BottleNeckCode) REFERENCES pdBottleNeckCodes (BottleNeckCode);
```

Now, I tried to insert a record in pdMaterialMaster where the referenced field BottleNeckCode is NULL, and got this error:

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__pdMateria__Bottl__7008F945"
```

Then, I changed the table definition like this:

```
ALTER TABLE [pdMaterialMaster]
 ALTER COLUMN [BottleNeckCode] varchar(2) NULL;
```

I still get the same error when trying to insert a row with a NULL value in this field.
It´s worth mentioning that table pdBottleNeckCodes has some entries.

What else should I do to allow NULL values in this field and get rid of this error?

Comment: . . You need to show the code you are using for the `insert`.

Comment: I [can't replicate](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8d9d493c0d3ec4b45fb82adce993ccd4) your problem.

Comment: I also strongly recommend naming your constraints/primary keys. The name `FK__pdMateria__Bottl__7008F945` is meaningless to anyone but the dataengine.

Comment: Are you sure that you store `NULL`, or is it perhaps storing `''` instead?

Comment: And how are you trying to `INSERT` those values? Depending on how your doing it, something a blank value may well be interpreted as `''` (which as @PeterB said, `''` is not `NULL`).

Comment: @Gordon 
The values I´m trying to insert come from a CSV file (one single record, for this test):

000000000000000260,

Comment: @Larnu You are right, I should.

Comment: @Peter B No, I am not sure; based on the sample data above I assume that 'no data' for that field, is treated as NULL

Comment: @Larnu That is a good question. This INSERT operation happens through a .NET engine and the actual SQL sentence is not visible for me

Comment: So you've written a .NET application to import the data? Then incluce the code for your .NET application and tag the appropriate language,.

Comment: @Larnu No, not really. I´m using one of these 'zero code environment' tools (called 'DECISIONS'), and I can´t have access to the code (or I don´t know how).

Comment: It seems very much like we're going down the route of the application is the problem here. if *you* can't control the data that is inserted, you'll need to insert it into a staging table, and then control the transformation into your production table.

Comment: @FAlvarez . . . I often load data into a staging table where all the column are strings.  Then I do the manipulations in the database for the final table format.  It might seem like extra work, but it avoids problems like this, and it often makes it easier to debug data issues.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that this .NET engine wasn´t transforming the empty string ('') into NULL, and therefore the FK validation error.
Thanks for your contribution.